# Terminology: name for the condition that makes the inequality an equality

Tags: inequality, terminology

Here are some famous inequalities:

**Arithmetic-Geometric mean**: If $x_1,...,x_n\in\Bbb{R}_{>0}$, then  $\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{x_1...x_n}$, and equality holds $\Leftrightarrow x_1=...=x_n$.

**Cauchy-Schwarz**: If $u,v\in\Bbb{R}^n$, then $\langle u, v\rangle\leq\|u\|\cdot\|v\|$ and equality holds $\Leftrightarrow u=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\neq 0$ or $v=0$.

In addition to these, we could cite so many other famous inequalities like Jensen's, Minkowski's, Harmonic-Geometric inequality, triangle inequality, etc, all of which end with a statement of the form "... and equality holds $\Leftrightarrow X$ happens".

It feels like this kind of statement, or the condition $X$ itself, should be given a special term. Is there a standard name for this?

I would probably call it "optimal condition", "critical condition" or something like that, but probably someone has given a decent name already.

Thank you!

Comment: equality condition?

Comment: I've never seen a term for this but it seems possible to me that it has been given a name in optimisation or maybe numerical analysis

Comment: Well, there is the notion of a "tight" inequality, if equality is possible for some subset of variables, and "strict" inequality, when equality is not possible (i.e. it is essentially ">" or "<").  Most famous inequalities are tight, they have an equality condition. Informally one also occasionally sees a notion of "tighter", when there are two tight bounds, one of which is superior for at least some values of the variables (i.e. $A\geqslant B$ is tighter than $A \geqslant C$ iff $B \geqslant C$.  Here $A=B=C$ is expected to hold for some choice of variables, as well.). Not sure if this helps.